How do I create a route for an area, defaulting the action name, and specifying the id after the slash (vs. "?id=")
How do I create a route for pages in an area, defaulting the action name, while allowing the id to be specified after the slash (vs. "?id=") in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC? I've read tons of articles online, tried several things and it simply won't work.
Here's the URL:
https://localhost:7280/Dashboard/Waterbody/1245839?at=organization&ttid=-1

This URL works:
https://localhost:7280/Dashboard/Waterbody/Index/1245839?at=organization&ttid=-1

but I don't want Index in it.
As does this one:
https://localhost:7280/Dashboard/Waterbody/?id=1245839&at=organization&ttid=-1

but I don't want ?id= in it.
Here's the section of Program.cs showing my route:
app.UseRouting();

app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Dashboard",
    areaName: "Dashboard",
    pattern: "Dashboard/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Here's the controller method signature:
public ActionResult Index(int id)

I tried adding this route before the others above, but it screws it up even more:
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Dashboard_Waterbody",
    areaName: "Dashboard",
    pattern: "Dashboard/{controller=Waterbody}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

This routing worked in the .NET Framework version of the site:
context.MapRoute(
    name: "Dashboard_Waterbody_Index",
    url: "Dashboard/Waterbody/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Waterbody", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Thing.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    name: "Dashboard_Default",
    url: "Dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { area= "Dashboard", action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Thing.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers" }
);

I'm not using custom routing attributes/filters on the controllers (ie: [Route("Dashboard/Waterbody/Index/{id}")], nor do I want to (why do it all over the place when I should be able to do it in Program.cs or Startup.cs?).
I find routing absolutely infuriating as it seems it's always a major pain to get setup. What's the deal? Simply directing me to another article will likely not work; someone's going to have to explain this to me very specifically.

You could try below code to set the route in the program file:
 // Specific route for Waterbody in Dashboard area
    app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "Dashboard_Waterbody",
        areaName: "Dashboard",
        pattern: "Dashboard/Waterbody/{id:int}",  
        defaults: new { controller = "Waterbody", action = "Index" }
    );
    
    // General area route
    app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "Dashboard",
        areaName: "Dashboard",
        pattern: "Dashboard/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

Controller:
public IActionResult Index(int id)
       

You could refer this document for more detail:
Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core
Areas in ASP.NET Core
